# Invoke std::function in an std::for_each

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have in essence the following code:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> fnGlobalChangeEvent;
typedef std::vector<fnGlobalChangeEvent> GlobalTriggers;

inline void ExecuteGlobal(fnGlobalChangeEvent ev)
{
    ev();
}

GlobalTriggers triggers;
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), std::bind(&ExecuteGlobal, _1));
```

The use of ExecuteGlobal feels totally redundant here, but I can't find the right syntax to drop out the call.

```
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), ExecuteGlobal(_1));
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), std::bind(_1));
```

Both fail to compile.

There is also a more complex case:

```
typedef std::function<void (Zot&)> fnChangeEvent;
typedef std::vector<fnChangeEvent> Triggers;

inline void Execute(fnChangeEvent ev, Zot& zot)
{
    ev(zot);
}

Triggers triggers;
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), std::bind(&Execute, _1, zot));
```

Is it possible to do without the helper functions in these cases?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the new `for` syntax in the latest C++ standard (C++11): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop

Comment: For your first example, the thing that's redundant is the use of std::bind: `std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), ExecuteGlobal);`

Comment: @benjamin-lindley: thanks, I was working back from the more complex case and missed the extra redundancy there!

Comment: For the record your second case might well work with `std::bind(&Execute, _1, std::ref(zot))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, a lambda:

```
std::for_each(
    triggers.begin(), triggers.end(),
    [](fnChangeEvent ev) { ev(); }
);
std::for_each(
     triggers.begin(), triggers.end(),
     [&zot](fnChangeEvent ev) { ev(zot); }
);
```

Or even better, range for:

```
for (auto ev : triggers) {
    ev();
}

// well, I think you can figure out the second one
```

Comment: The lambda works ... but given that I already had a function in effect as the iterator variable it just felt there should be a way of using it directly without having to create an new wrapper at all.

Comment: @RobWalker: That is also possible, but for that you've to use Boost. Can you use that?

Comment: Actually you would need a very recent compiler, since those things are from the newest C++ standard (2011).

Comment: @Ivella: OP is already using C++11 features (`std::bind` and `std::function`).

Comment: @Nawaz: ironically this code was added because we were trying  to *drop* the dependency we had on Boost!  Switching to the std::* form from boost::* exposed some stuff Boost had been more 'forgiving' of, and this was involved in the clean up.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: currently this is in VS2010 ... the std::bind/function stuff compiles but the range based loops don't

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use lambda as:

```
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), 
              triggers.end(), 
              [&](fnChangeEvent & e) 
              {
                   e(zot);
              });
```

Or using range-based for loop as:

```
for (auto& e : triggers)  { e(zot); }
```

which looks more concise and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I just thought up, tell me if it's something like what you're looking for:

```
template<typename IT, typename ...Args>
void call_each(IT begin_, IT end_, Args&&... args)
{
    for (auto i = begin_; i!=end_; ++i)
        (*i)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
call_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end());
```

And for functions with arguments:

```
call_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), zot);
```

Comment: Bad idea. You are using the function template `std::forward` the wrong way. If an rvalue is passed to `call_each`, the _object_ can be moved away in the first iteration, and the other iterations will use the wrong _object_.

Answer (score 0):

Just, so I won't forget that option:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> fnGlobalChangeEvent;
typedef std::vector<fnGlobalChangeEvent> GlobalTriggers;

GlobalTriggers triggers;
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::for_each(triggers.begin(), triggers.end(), std::bind(&fnGlobalChangeEvent::operator(), _1));
```